# Excel VBA Macro - Can it be simplified or structured differently?

Tags: excel, vba

I made a simple VBA macro that I run against a CSV file that I open in excel.  This macro formats the sheet, deletes certain data, inserts columns, etc.  It then copies the properly formatted CSV to a server where the data is imported into our ERP. The CSV file is a Bill of Material and everything works great.  I am wondering if it could be simplified.  When I import this macro as an excel add-in, instead of showing one macro, it shows all the various sub-routines within the macro, along with the main sub that calls all the other subs in the order I need them to run.  Is there a better way to arrange this code?

```
Sub ProcessBOM()
    Call DeleteColumn
    Call DelBinFill
    Call DelBlankRows
    Call Insert3Columns
    Call DelRow1
    Call ClearColumns
    Call InsertProjectName
    Call InsertLineItemNo
    Call InsertEA
    Call MoveColumn
    Call InsertDate
    Call GetUserName
    Call SaveAs
    Call MessageBox
End Sub

'Delete first column
Sub DeleteColumn()
    Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub

'Delete rows containing BIN FILL
Sub DelBinFill()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 1) = "BIN FILL" Then Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    Next i
End Sub

'Delete rows with blank RDI Item #
Sub DelBlankRows()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 1) = "" Then Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    Next i
End Sub

'Insert 3 blank columns
Sub Insert3Columns()
    Range("A:C").EntireColumn.Insert
End Sub

'Delete Row 1
Sub DelRow1()
    Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub

'Clear Contents of specified columns
Sub ClearColumns()
    Range("E:G").EntireColumn.Clear
End Sub

'Grabs Project Name from Active Sheet and inserts to last row
Sub InsertProjectName()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("C1:C" & LastRow) = ActiveSheet.Name
End Sub

'Insert Line Item Numbers
Sub InsertLineItemNo()
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    LastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A" & LastRow), Type:=xlFillSeries
End Sub

'Insert EA Into Column E
Sub InsertEA()
    LastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("E1:E" & LastRow) = "EA"
End Sub

' Moves QTY Data from H to F
Sub MoveColumn()
    Columns("H:H").Select
    Selection.Cut Destination:=Columns("F:F")
    Columns("F:F").Select
End Sub

'Insert Date Into Column G
Sub InsertDate()
    Dim LDate As String
    LDate = Date
    LastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("G1:G" & LastRow).Resize(, 2) = Array(Date, "=""""")
End Sub

'Get logged on username and insert into Column B
Sub GetUserName()
    Dim strName As String
    strName = Environ("UserName")
    LastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("B1:B" & LastRow) = strName
End Sub

'Save file
Sub SaveAs()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    MyName = ActiveSheet.Name
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="\\navapp1svr\boms$\solidworks\inbound" & "\" & MyName & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlText
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub

'Prompt the user to verify data upload in Microsoft Dynamics NAV
Sub MessageBox()
    MsgBox ("BOM upload complete.  Please check Dynamics for accuracy.")
End Sub
```

Comment: `InsertLineItemNo` makes no sense. How do you know what the "ActiveCell" or the "Selected" range is at this point in your procedure. That is risky business right there.

Comment: Do you call these subroutines anywhere else? If not this seems WAY over-refactored and makes your code really hard to follow.

Comment: For instance you have to recalc `LastRow` over and over and over again even though it never changes. Why not do that in your main sub and pass that as a parameter to these other subroutines? Or just remove the subroutines and do all this step-by-step rinky dink logic as a single routine.

Comment: In `InsertDate` you declare and set `LDate` but never use it.

Comment: For a routine like `DelBinFill`, I would create a parameter that defines the string to look for (in this case, it's "BIN FILL "). That way, you could potentially reuse the routine at some point and/or more easily change the value to compare. Same for things like `DeleteColumn` -- make the column number a parameter. I do agree with @JNevill that it seems over-refactored but at the same time you need to keep doing what you're doing. You'll learn what your own style and balance is on coding and maintaining your own code.

Comment: With a nice title that describes the purpose of the code, this would be a much better fit for [codereview.se]

Comment: Are you only keeping the original columns B and F or are there other columns?  How many columns are in the original data?

Answer (score 5):

I think this is primarily opinion based, but I have a strong opinion here so I'm sharing it. I feel like your code is way over-refactored and there is some extra superfluous stuff in here (variables being set but never used, `.SELECT` being used to copy/paste,  variables declared and set and then only used once)

Consider a single routine:

```
Sub ProcessBOM()
    Dim i As Integer

    'Delete first column
    Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete

    'Delete rows containing BIN FILL or Nothing
    For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 1) = "BIN FILL" OR Cells(i, 1) = "" Then Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    Next i

    'Insert 3 blank columns
    Range("A:C").EntireColumn.Insert

    'Delete Row 1
    Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete

    'Clear Contents of specified columns
    Range("E:G").EntireColumn.Clear

    'Define last used row
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Grabs Project Name from Active Sheet and inserts to last row
    Range("C1:C" & LastRow) = ActiveSheet.Name

    'Insert Line Item Numbers
        'What is this. How do you know what the "ActiveCell" is at this point or what is "Selected"
        'Commenting out because this is risky. Explicitly set which cells you want to do this to
    'ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
    'Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A" & LastRow),Type:=xlFillSeries

    'Insert EA Into Column E
    Range("E1:E" & LastRow) = "EA"

    ' Moves QTY Data from H to F
    Columns("H:H").Cut Destination:=Columns("F:F")

    'Insert Date Into Column G
    Range("G1:G" & LastRow).Resize(, 2) = Array(Date, "=""""")

    'Get logged on username and insert into Column B
    Range("B1:B" & LastRow) = Environ("UserName")

    'Save file
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="\\navapp1svr\boms$\solidworks\inbound" & "\" & ActiveSheet.Name & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlText   
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

    'Prompt the user to verify data upload in Microsoft Dynamics NAV
    MsgBox ("BOM upload complete.  Please check Dynamics for accuracy.")
End Sub
```

It's only 54 rows including comments and whitespace . In fact, it's only 23 lines of actual code. It's very clear what each step is doing and it can be read by a human without bouncing from the top routine down to whatever step is next. Your getting really close to spaghetti-code and you don't want to go there.

Expanding this out into 15 subroutines doesn't really make sense as they don't really encapsulate much more than a line or two of code and they aren't terribly reusable as they all do a VERY specific thing to a specific range that is only applicable at a single point-in-time while your code is running. If you have more code that may need to reuse some of the code that is present here, then MAYBE consider separating out the logic into it's own subroutine.

There are some pieces that *might* make sense as their own subroutine or function. For instance you have two routines that are similar `DelBinFill` and `DelBlankRows`. These could be written as a single routine with a parameter:

```
Sub DelRows(criteria As String)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 1) = criteria Then Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    Next i
End Sub
```

And called like:

```
Call DelRows("Bin Fill")
Call DelRows("")
```

But... now you have to loop through the same range twice and delete rows. It would be MUCH more efficient to loop once (as I do above) and delete based on both criteria.

Comment: Once you delete all the comments, it will be easy to see how much simpler this is. Turning this into 14 subs is not necessary

Comment: Hi JNevil, thank you for your help so far.  The InsertLineItemNo is intended to create a number sequence from top row to the last row.  Our system needs each line in the list to start with a number. I am sure there is a better way to accomplish this, that is why I shared this with the forum - You are mostly experts and I am a noob ;)

Comment: Thank you all for your input - I desire to be a good programmer someday, and this is very helpful.

Comment: You could just do `=Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Formula = "=Row()"` and it will populate the cell with row number it's on.

Comment: Also, I will use code review forum next time I have a post like this.